# Clearing a Nested QList: Risk of Memory Leak?

Tags: qt, c++11, memory-leaks

Is it necessary to clear all the inner lists to avoid a leak?:

```
class Instruction
{
    int opcode;
    int data1;
    int data2;

    bool Load(QTextStream* in);
    void Save(QTextStream* out) const;
};

class Interpreter
{
    QList<QList<Instruction>> steps;

    bool Load(QTextStream* file)
    {
        if(file_is_bad)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int end = steps.size();
        for(int i=0; i<end; i++)
        {
            steps.at(i).clear();
        }
        steps.clear();

        //now that it's clear, rebuild it from file
        return true;
    }
};
```

Or can I just call steps.clear(); and call it a day?

---

(And here's some more text to get past the "too much code" error.)

Comment: `steps.clear()` alone is sufficient. It runs destructors on all its elements, and `QList` destructor is essentially the same as `clear()`

Comment: though if inner list contains pointers created with new, qDeleteAll() should be called for each nested list as well

Comment: If `Instruction` doesn't produce memory leaks, `QList<QList<Instruction>>` on stack won't as well. You can run valgrind to check for memory leaks.

Comment: @SimonWarta: Does it make a difference if Interpreter is in the heap (via new), seeing that the QList<Qlist<Instruction>> is a member object?

Comment: @AaronD I was not really precise with my wording (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/11477572). Since it is a member, `QList<QList<Instruction>> steps;` is properly destroyed as soon as your `Interpreter` instance is destroyed, from heap or from stack. So "just call steps.clear(); and call it a day".

Comment: @SimonWarta: Okay.  If you'd like to make an answer to that effect, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor was right. `steps.clear()` is enough because it destroys all inner QLists. Destroying an inner QList calls the destructor of all `Instruction` instants.

So as long as a single `Instruction` does not leak memory (e.g. by calling a `new` in the constructor but no `delete` in the destructor), `QList<QList<Instruction>>` will not leak as well.